# Adjust p:tree to use available height

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My program logic is working which is good, but I can't figure out how to make the critical components adjust their size to the available height of the screen.  For example I have:

```
            <p:layout id="workLayout" style="margin-top: 5px; height: 95%">

                <p:layoutUnit position="west"
                              resizable="true"
                              minSize="50"
                              size="200">

                    <h:form id="treeForm">
                        <p:tree value="#{workspace.listTree}"
                                var="node"
                                >
                            <p:treeNode>
                                <h:outputText value="#{node.name}" />
                            </p:treeNode>
                        </p:tree>
                    </h:form>

                </p:layoutUnit>
```

What happens is that it renders a the layout height of about 200px.  (The CSS height term has no effect).   As soon as you expand a few nodes in the tree then you have to start vertical scrolling while at the same time there is a lot of wasted white space below the p:layout space.

Any hint on how to do this?

**Update:** I discovered that I can get close to the effect that I want if I enter an absolute height like this:

```
<p:layout id="workLayout" style="margin-top: 5px; height: 6in">
```

It seems that a height value is dependent on some exterior container.  However if that is the case why is the object able to resize itself when I change the horizontal size of the browser window?  What I want is for it to respond to the vertical size as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my component code that uses the PrimeNg p-tree control, I use an input string variable and assign it to the ui-tree class height. You can then set it to pixel or percent height:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef} from '@angular/core 

export class PersonnelTreeComponent implements OnInit {

        @Input() height: string;
        treeheight: string = '400px';  

        constructor( private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) { } 

        ngOnInit() { 
            if (this.height != null) {
                this.treeheight = this.height;
            }  
        }  

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.ui-tree'), 'height', this.treeheight );  
        } 
    }
```

You then set it in the usual way:

```
<personneltree-component  [height]="'100%'"></personneltree-component>
```

Comment: Before I saw your answer I had no idea that there was a PrimeFaces library for Angular.   It looks interesting.

Comment: I used this for 'width':'100%' couldn't find an easiest way for a such a simple thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Primefaces **3.5** the CSS of `p:tree` starts with

```
.ui-tree {
width: 300px;
position: relative;
}
.ui-tree .ui-tree-container {
margin: 0;
padding: 3px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: auto;
}
```

I would use `style` attribute  to add the CSS property use need: `height:100%`: `<p:tree style="height:100%"/>`.

**Before** changing the code though, add this style to the tree using the developer tools of Chrome or Firefox to make sure it works!

Comment: good idea but it didn't seem to pan out.  The container of the p:tree is the p:layoutUnit and I have to somehow adjust that and let the p:tree expand to fill that space.